# Browsers can't detect my webcam but it works in cheese

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, 21.10, devices, detect

Suddenly, my webcam stopped working in my browsers even though it works if I run the `cheese` application in the terminal. I am testing it with [this website](https://it.webcamtests.com/check) (and many others) on Google Chrome (incognito mode and Firefox) and I get this error message:

> NotFoundError: Requested device not found; Object

`lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57f2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I use an external webcam this still does not get detected. I tried to re-install Chrome, change user and reboot my machine but still does not work. Microphone, instead, is correctly detected.

My system information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
Kernel:         5.13.0-23-generic
```

`ls -l /dev/video*` prints

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 gen  6 18:06 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 gen  6 18:06 /dev/video1
```

`groups $USER` prints

```
alex : alex adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

`bash ./pathlld /dev/video*` prints

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 gen  6 12:46 /
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4960 gen  6 19:14 /dev
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=6036388k,nr_inodes=1509097,mode=755,inode64)
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 gen  6 19:12 /dev/video0
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 gen  6 12:46 /
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4960 gen  6 19:14 /dev
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=6036388k,nr_inodes=1509097,mode=755,inode64)
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 gen  6 19:12 /dev/video1
```

`getfacl /dev/video*` prints

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/video0
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rw-
user:alex:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/video1
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rw-
user:alex:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: Can you try in _Incognito_ mode? Can you try with _Firefox_?

Comment: @FedKad not working on both

Comment: Did you tried accepting "web device access permissions" when website request it?.

Comment: @MatthiasLenmher Yes, of course. I tried to re-install chrome as well

Comment: Can you try rebooting with an older kernel (in advanced options in the GRUB menu)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi same problem

Comment: Can you try the same with a _newly created Ubuntu user_?

Comment: @FedKad same problem

Comment: I guess the problematic applications are installed as snap packages and you might need to configure their permissions, you can do so from within the snap-store.

Comment: @mook765 How? ..

Comment: @tail Open the snap-store or software-center or however you call it, search for the applications and look for the `Permissions`-button.

Comment: @mook765 I can't find Permission button if I click on Google Chrome on Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: @tail You can check with `snap list` which applications are installed as snaps. You wrote `Google Chrome (downloaded by terminal)`, what does this mean exactly? It's probably not a snap.

Comment: @mook765 I downloaded the deb file and install it via terminal (it is not a snap). Anyway I am still facing issues with webcam on any browsers

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @MarcinErbel no

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`. Your camera is probably `/dev/video`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: I can't simply connect my device because my webcam is integrated. Anyway if I run `ls -l /dev | grep video` there are shown video0 and video1. What should I pick? I suppose it is `dev/video0` as you said and if I list I get: `crw-rw----+`. So I `device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)`. I reboot my computer and `newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)`. Is there any mistake? This still does not work

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: Try `bash ./pathlld /dev/video*`, or `chmod +x ./pathlld` followed by `./pathlld /dev/video*`. By running a `bash` script with the less capable `sh`, you broke it.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @tail The output of `groups $USER` looks as if you shortened it. Please post original output instead of edited command output. Also interesting to see output of `getfacl /dev/video*`.

Comment: @mook765 I edited my post. Check it out

Comment: @tail The ACL's tell us, that user alex has rw-permission on both files, you wouldn't even need to be in the video group. The ACL's look ok, same on my system. Also groups are the same for my user with the exeption of the video group which I don't need to access the camera. Sorry, no idea where to look next...